# How can one verify the port configuration of a firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, port

I am a contractor on a project and have provided a port configuration requirement to the Server Hosting service provider for my project.  How can I verify that the ports are configured and "open" for me to complete my server-app install?

Since I do not yet have a working server, is it possible to test ports without a listener?

Are there tools available to be the listener? -- I have Network Utility on Mac to be the port scanner.

I need this before I can approve the work is complete, and I don't want to have to go back and ask for more changes resulting from an incomplete test.

Comment: Have you ever heard of 'nmap'?

Comment: Or do you have a machine somewhere you can remote to and try to access from that?

Comment: Yes, I found 'nmap' and installed, however, it appears that I need a purchased version to test more than one port?!??!  When I did scan, it just looped forever -- I think I need a listener on the server.  Clearly, I don't know how to properly use nmap.

Comment: Yes, I have access to both machines.  I rewrote my description since the fundamental question I think needs to be address is to have a listener acting as a web-app / web-service.  Am I correct in that statement?

Comment: Try to utilize answers from [this question](http://superuser.com/q/397892/238539)

Comment: Take a look at netcat. A little console tool that perfectly suits your needs. You can create sender and listener with a short one-liner, this is perfect for testing ports.

Comment: @Atari: Nmap does not help him as there's nothing listening yet. You could only tell if the port is blocked or filtered, nothing more.

Comment: @Robert --- that is what I am looking for.  If you post as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at netcat. A little console tool that perfectly suits your needs. You can create sender and listener with a short one-liner, this is perfect for testing ports.