# Start a service that listens on specified port?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012

Is there a easy way to start a service/program that listens on a specific port?

I just want to be able to verify that the firewall opening is correct.

Comment: Start the service that should be running on that port and check on it with a simple telnet?

Comment: I can't, its an external dev saying that that the port opening isen't done. But there is no service listening so ofc it doesn't work, so i wanna open something up to just prove to him that it's open

Comment: Just tell him that there is no service running so it's no wonder he can't connect?

Comment: You can use [`netcat`](https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/)

Comment: Politics are involved so it's not really that simple

Comment: Did you bother to look at the link I gave you? It is a Windows port of netcat ...

Comment: You want netcat (`nc`). Or similar. Or a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to connect to a port you have to have some kind of service running. Some really simple [webserver](https://gist.github.com/wagnerandrade/5424431) might be an option (didn't test that one). Other Stackoverflow questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/397892/utility-to-open-tcp-port-to-listen-state) have some more options. You should be able to get something going with most scripting languages. This [article](https://geekflare.com/create-port-listener-in-windows-or-linux/) has an example for Python and has a link to some real light weight software called [Port Listener](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/portlistener/).

After you have a service running you can use telnet to check whenever you're able to connect.

Comment: Perfect, port listener seems like exactly what i need